# Progress bar between two dates (fetch "var" from script), HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to make a progress bar that advances between two dates that have been set beforehand. I've mixed code from an elapsed time counter and a progress bar. The time counter within the script-tags gets the difference in minutes between the dates as well as the distance in minutes from the current date (this latter is the progression). What I'd like to do is to replace the value for "aria-valuenow" with the value in the variable "progress"; as I see it, this would suffice to get the current advancement between the dates in percent. How should the syntax look like to access this "progress" variable from outside the script, in the code for the progress bar?

```js
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();
    var startDate = new Date("Dec 1, 2018, 10:00:00").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distanceWhole = countDownDate - startDate;
 var distanceLeft = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for minutes and percentage progressed
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor(distanceLeft / (1000 * 60));
 var minutesTotal = Math.floor(distanceWhole / (1000 * 60));
 var progress = Math.floor(((minutesTotal - minutesLeft) / minutesTotal) * 100);
    }, 1000);
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
 <p id="demo"></p>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This displays only some hard-coded value as the progress status. How to make it correspond to any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an complete working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();
        var startDate = new Date("Dec 1, 2018, 10:00:00").getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
// Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distanceWhole = countDownDate - startDate;
        var distanceLeft = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for minutes and percentage progressed
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor(distanceLeft / (1000 * 60));
        var minutesTotal = Math.floor(distanceWhole / (1000 * 60));
        var progress = Math.floor(((minutesTotal - minutesLeft) / minutesTotal) * 100);
        $('#progressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', progress).css('width', progress + "%").html(progress + "% Complete");
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="progress">
            <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                70% Complete
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
$('#progressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', progress ).css('width', progress );
```

Comment: Is this CSS-code that should be placed in the head, within style-tags? If so, I don't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: This is javascript code. You must put if after calculate the progress

Comment: I've added it after the "var progress = ..." line in the javascript but the progress bar doesn't update. I have two thoughts: should it not be "style" instead of "width" in your suggestion, and perhaps the variable progress needs to be updated to progress = "width:" + progress + "%" to follow the syntax in the original example. Also, should the aria-valuenow="70" and style="width:70% be kept or removed?

Answer (score 0):

My pure JavaScript solution based on Juan's answer:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var progress = document.getElementById("progress");

// Set start and end date
var endDate = new Date("Mar 1, 2021 10:00:00").getTime();
var startDate = new Date("Jun 20, 2020, 10:00:00").getTime();

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distanceWhole = endDate - startDate;
var distanceLeft = endDate - now;

// Time calculations for minutes and percentage progressed
var minutesLeft = Math.floor(distanceLeft / (1000 * 60));
var minutesTotal = Math.floor(distanceWhole / (1000 * 60));
var result = Math.floor(((minutesTotal - minutesLeft) / minutesTotal) * 100);

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(addFrame, 100);
}

function addFrame() {
    if (result < 100) {
        progress.style.width = result + "%";
        progress.innerHTML = result + "%";
    }
}
```

```css
#progressBar {
    height: 25px;
    width: 70%;
    background: #dbcdbf;
    border: 1px solid rgba(244, 241, 237, 0);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#progress {
    background: #b36b24;
    color: #555;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 2s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBar">
    <p id="progress"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I want this to get running on a server how do I have to name the files?

Comment: You can combine everything in a single HTML and use the HTML "style" and "script" tags to add the CSS and JavaScript code, then name it index.html and upload it to the webserver. Or you can use separate .css and .js files and link them in your main HTML file. I would suggest the following naming and structure: index.html (contains the HTML code); style.css (contains the styles); script.js (contains the logic)